# Sentence structure of "South Africans are demanding world’s largest diamond is returned from the Queen' Crown Jewels."

Tags: grammar, sentence

Sentence:

> South Africans are demanding 'world's largest diamond' is returned from The Queen's crown jewels

Source: [Unilad News](https://www.unilad.com/news/queen-owns-south-africa-diamond-20220916#:%7E:text=South%20Africans%20are%20demanding%20%27world%27s,from%20The%20Queen%27s%20crown%20jewels&text=More%20than%206%2C000%20people%20have,Africa%2C%20where%20it%20was%20mined.)

Q: Could anyone please explain me about this sentence structure? The two words "is returned" sounds rather confusing to me, shouldn't the use of "to be returned" correct? As the jewel has not been returned in this case.

Comment: It's ungrammatical.

Comment: Please tell us where you read this sentence. Apart from anything else, 'the queen jewel' makes no sense.

Comment: Of course, @JohnLawler already wrote an answer about the correct phrasing here (the [subjunctive](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/116698/191178), see #1 in the list).

Comment: It's "headlinese", reduced from something like *South Africans are demanding [**that**] **the** world’s largest diamond [**should**] **be** returned [**to** South Africa, **from** The Queen's crown jewels].*

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I wouldn't capitalise 'The' in 'the queen', and as a Guardian reader, wouldn't do so for the queen either.

Comment: I would also note that Queen Elizabeth II died on September 8 2022, and the UK now has a king (or 'a King' if you read the _Daily Mail_). The **Crown Jewels** of the United Kingdom are a collection of royal ceremonial objects kept in the Tower of London, which include the coronation regalia and vestments worn by British monarchs.

Comment: I've copied a corrected version of the headline to the questin

Comment: @KateBunting I read this sentence on Unilad news website. If the sentence is grammatically incorrect, what is the correct sentence for the same?

Comment: @JamesK - that headline was written 8 days after 'the queen' died, so perhaps the reporter's research skill or general knowledge were a little poor?

Comment: I would prefer 'South Africans are demanding that the 'world's largest diamond' is returned from the United Kingdom's Crown Jewels'. Old fashioned people might prefer the subjunctive 'be returned'. Also, if the Cullinan I diamond is officially the _world's largest diamond_, I would not surround that phrase with quote marks.

Comment: The old queen is dead. The new queen, Camilla, is not the custodian, keeper. or owner of the Crown Jewels. Neither is the king.

Comment: The _Daily Express_ sometimes capitalises 'king' and sometimes doesn't, occasionally in the same story. I don't think the explanation is that it is striving for balance between monarchy worship (the 'British Shinto') and republicanism, rather that it is simply a bad newspaper.

Comment: Nityananthan, the sentence _as quoted accurately_ is 'headlinese' and not required to be strictly grammatical. Michael has provided a correct version as a proper sentence.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  No, it's not "old fashioned people". It's all 333 million Americans. :)

Comment: @tchrist - I apologise; I was thinking of the decline of the subjunctive in British English, and, I am sorry to say, in French, for many.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in comments, this is headlinese, with the usual compression and omitted words that is common in the style.

The structure is

South Africans(subject)  are(aux verb) demanding(participle, forming present continuous) ...(object)

The object is a content clause (aka nominal clause, ie a clause acting like a noun), these are often marked with a subordinator "that", but it has been omitted in this case. The structure of the content clause is:

'worlds largest diamond' (subject, by marking it in quotes it means "the thing that is called the world largest diamond, even if this isn't literally true")  is (aux verb) returned (past participle, forming passive voice).

This content clause could have used the subjunctive "be returned".  But in modern British English, that isn't required.

Finally there is a prepositional phrase which is supplemental to the content clause "from (prepostion) The Queen's crown jewels (object)"

Comment: The subjunctive is definitely required in American English here. As John Lawler said, this is ungrammatical here.

Comment: @tchrist The queen would have disagreed with you.